# Solr More Like This (MLT) using a different unique identifier than the default one id

Tags: solr, morelikethis

I m trying to use MLT but I have as unique identifier doc_id instead of id and if I do this :

`http://localhost:8983/solr/mlt/?q=doc_id:question#11` I have no results

where If I do this
    `http://localhost:8983/solr/mlt/?q=id:11` I have results

```
<requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="mlt.fl">title,text</str>
     <str name="mlt.mintf">1</str>
     <str name="mlt.mindf">2</str>
     <str name="mlt.minwl">2</str>
     <str name="mlt.boost">true</str>
     <int name="rows">5</int>
     <str name="fl">id,doc_id,title,content_type,user_id,topic_id,score</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

How can I use MLT with doc_id as my unique identifier ?

Comment: Avoid use of '#' in your identifiers: in an URL context, an unescaped '#' is a client-side 'reference' identifer, and clients (like web browsers and perhaps your web-request library) won't send the "#etc" portion of the URL. If you must use a '#' in an URL, it must be URL-encoded, as '%23'.

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks fine. MLT just users the query to find a doc and if found use that doc for the source document. Are you sure a document is returned with the query "doc_id:question#11".   Put the value in quotes and see if that get you the document back, ex. doc_id:"question#11".  What is the datatype for doc_id?

Comment: I ve tried like that : doc_id:"question#11" and I ve got an error : Problem accessing /solr/mlt/. 

Reason:
Query parsing error: Cannot parse 'doc_id:"question': Lexical error at line 1, column 17.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "\"question"

If I try like that : doc_id:'question#11' nothing is returned.

The definition of doc_id <field name="doc_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

Comment: Is it possible you are not url encoding the query? I tried this locally and it worked fine.  If you pasted and tested the query you mentioned locally it should look something like this:
http://localhost:8080/solr/mlt/?q=doc_id%3A"document%2314"

Comment: that s correct, after replacing # by %23 in the url it start working, thanks